# Merging and concatinating simultaneously

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have multiple data frames, each representing monthly progress.
My mission is to join them with two condition step by step.
So here is three sample data frame, and I will try to explain what I want to achieve.

```
import pandas as pd

data_22_3 = {
    'id_number': ['A123', 'B456', 'C789'],
    'company': ['Insurance1', 'Insurance2', 'Insurance3'],
    'type': ['A', 'A', 'C'],
    'Income': [100, 200, 300]
}
df_22_3 = pd.DataFrame(data_22_3)

data_22_4 = {
    'id_number': ['A123', 'B456', 'D012'],
    'company': ['Insurance1', 'Insurance2', 'Insurance1'],
    'type': ['A', 'B', 'B'],
    'Income': [150, 250, 400]
}
df_22_4 = pd.DataFrame(data_22_4)

data_22_5 = {
    'id_number': ['A123', 'C789', 'E034'],
    'company': ['Insurance1', 'Insurance3', 'Insurance5'],
    'type': ['A', 'C', 'B'],
    'Income': [180, 320, 500]
}
df_22_5 = pd.DataFrame(data_22_5)
```

So, let's take the first data frame as the main data frame. The joining first and second data frame should be as following:

If `id_number` of second data frame exists on the first one, then the new column of `Income_2`  should be added to the first data frame as the next month's income. Since the next data frame has the same columns, all of the columns except `Income` should be disregarded.

If `id_number` of second data frame does not exist on the first one, then the whole row should be added to the first data frame. The only thing to consider is to place `Income` value to the `Income_2` column, and putting 0 to the `Income` column, since the value belongs to the next month.

The resulting data frame then should be joined with the next dataframe in a similar method and so on.

Even if there is a difference on values of other columns such as `Type` or `Company`, as long as `id_number` is the same, the former data frame value should be taken.

I might be explaining inadequately, but the result is something like this:

```
data_all = {
    'id_number': ['A123', 'B456', 'C789', 'D012', 'E034'],
    'company': ['Insurance1', 'Insurance2', 'Insurance3', 'Insurance1', 'Insurance5'],
    'type': ['A', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'B'],
    'Income': [100, 200, 300, 0, 0],
    'Income_2': [150, 250, 0, 400, 0],
    'Income_3': [180, 0, 320, 0, 500]
}

all_df = pd.DataFrame(data_all)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of simultaneously, concat first (without `Income`) and drop duplicates, then merge each `Income`.

```
dfs = [df_22_3, df_22_4, df_22_5]
result = (
    pd.concat(dfs)
    .drop(columns='Income')
    .drop_duplicates('id_number')
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

For the merge, manually reindexing is the cleanest way I found to fill missing values:

```
for i, df in enumerate(dfs, start=1):
    result[f'Income_{i}'] = (
        df
        .set_index('id_number')
        ['Income']
        .reindex(result['id_number'], fill_value=0)
        .reset_index(drop=True)
    )
```

At this point I have the result's `Income` column labelled as `Income_1` for consistency, but it can be renamed:

```
result.rename(columns={'Income_1': 'Income'})
```

```
  id_number     company type  Income  Income_2  Income_3
0      A123  Insurance1    A     100       150       180
1      B456  Insurance2    A     200       250         0
2      C789  Insurance3    C     300         0       320
3      D012  Insurance1    B       0       400         0
4      E034  Insurance5    B       0         0       500
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```py
out = pd.concat(
    [
        df_22_3.set_index("id_number"),
        df_22_4.set_index("id_number")[["company", "type", "Income"]].add_suffix("_2"),
        df_22_5.set_index("id_number")[["company", "type", "Income"]].add_suffix("_3"),
    ],
    axis=1,
).reset_index()

out["company"] = out[["company", "company_2", "company_3"]].apply(
    lambda x: x[x.first_valid_index()], axis=1
)

out["type"] = out[["type", "type_2", "type_3"]].apply(
    lambda x: x[x.first_valid_index()], axis=1
)

out = out.drop(columns=["type_2", "type_3", "company_2", "company_3"]).fillna(0)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
  id_number     company type  Income  Income_2  Income_3
0      A123  Insurance1    A   100.0     150.0     180.0
1      B456  Insurance2    B   200.0     250.0       0.0
2      C789  Insurance3    C   300.0       0.0     320.0
3      D012  Insurance1    B     0.0     400.0       0.0
4      E034  Insurance5    B     0.0       0.0     500.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could concat all your data together first (long format), add a column for the source df number, then pivot the `Income`s accordingly. For the other columns, get the first values separately and join.

```
dfs = [df_22_3, df_22_4, df_22_5]
df = pd.concat([d.assign(n=n) for n, d in enumerate(dfs, start=1)])

# Columns
primary = 'id_number'
pivot = 'Income'
number = 'n'

income_pivot = (
    # Same as `df.pivot`, but with a `fill_value`
    df.set_index([primary, number])[pivot].unstack(number, fill_value=0)
    # Change labels
    .add_prefix(f'{pivot}_').rename_axis(columns=None)
)

other_cols_first = df.drop(columns=[pivot, number]).groupby(primary).first()

result = other_cols_first.join(income_pivot)
```

```
              company type  Income_1  Income_2  Income_3
id_number
A123       Insurance1    A       100       150       180
B456       Insurance2    A       200       250         0
C789       Insurance3    C       300         0       320
D012       Insurance1    B         0       400         0
E034       Insurance5    B         0         0       500
```

At this point, to get the exact output you showed, you can just rename the `Income_1` column and reset the index.

```
result.rename(columns={'Income_1': 'Income'}).reset_index()
```

```
  id_number     company type  Income  Income_2  Income_3
0      A123  Insurance1    A     100       150       180
1      B456  Insurance2    A     200       250         0
2      C789  Insurance3    C     300         0       320
3      D012  Insurance1    B       0       400         0
4      E034  Insurance5    B       0         0       500
```